# Amazon S3 Bucket replica location

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, replication

I am confusing about the Amazon S3 replica mechanism. In my understanding, by default, Amazon S3 applies 3-replica mechanism, in which there will be 3 replicas for each object created on my S3 bucket. And all the replicas are stored in multiple availability zones within only ONE region, which I specified when creating S3 bucket. 
Is my understanding correct? If it's correct, is it possible to see where the replicas of an object are stored?

Thanks

Comment: There appear to be at least three copies kept (as [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/reduced-redundancy/) says standard redundancy storage can survive two datacenter outages). They're stored within the region (although at one point "US Standard" meant they were in both West and East coast DCs - I believe that's no longer the case). You can't get any visibility on where the replicas are stored to my knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

You are pretty much correct. S3 replication works by replicating across at least 3 data centers, over at least two AZs within a single region (each availability zone can have multiple data centers).

The replication is part of s3, which is a managed service, meaning you just have to accept what they're telling you. Telling you where the replicas were wouldn't really serve any purpose, and AWS never really disclose the details of their infrastructure to anyone who doesn't need to know. Even if they told you the data was stored in Availability Zone 1 and 2, this is effectively meaningless information, as zones are aliases, i.e your Zone 1 probably isn't the same as my Zone 1.